# How to config One-way SSL in http:outbound-gateway

Tags: ssl, spring-integration

There is chapter [31.10.2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html) in spring integration reference for SSL support, however I can't make it work with http:outbound-gateway, may I know is there any sample configuration for one-way ssl with http:outbound-gateway for me to have a reference?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That SSL support is provided for the TCP/IP components and yes that definitely won't work for HTTP.

The Spring Integration HTTP Outbound Gateway is fully based on the Spring Web `RestTemplate`. So, what you can do there with SSL is fully applied for Spring Integration HTTP.

I suggest you to take a look into the `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` which can be simply injected into the `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` via `request-factory`. And that one, in turn, can be supplied with the Apache Common `HttpClient`. The SSL will be configured there already:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient
  = HttpClients.custom()
    .setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier())
    .build();
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory 
  = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my configuration based on Artem Bilan's response.
need to define 2 beans  for SSL

```
<http:outbound-gateway expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
                               url="${gateway.host}/SearchAll"
                               http-method="POST"
                               extract-request-payload="true"
                               request-factory="sslFactory">
        </http:outbound-gateway>


    <!--SSL-->
    <bean id="sslFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="httpClient"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="httpClient" class="com.oocl.frm.dmtp.component.ssl.HttpClientFactory" />
```